# C- How to free the following malloced memory

Tags: c, malloc, free

Can someone please help me on how to free the two dimensional array here. I tried using the loop to free but i get an error saying:

```
 *** glibc detected *** ./assignment4: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0932b196 ***
```

The thing is when i free the 0th element alone i dont get any problem. But when i free elements [1] to [7] i get the error.

```
char ** stringOne; 
stringOne = malloc(sizeof(char*)*8);

stringOne[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
stringOne[0] = strtok(listofdetails[0], " ");

for(i=1;i<8;i++)
{
    stringOne[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringOne[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
}

for(i=0;i<8;i++) // FREEING memory
{
    free(stringOne[i]);
}
```

Comment: Your indentation looks weird..

Comment: Compile with warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux). Use a memory leak detector like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) when available. Test against failure of `malloc`. Use `calloc` for arrays of pointers.

Answer (score 9):

The `strtok` function returns a pointer into the string you're tokenizing, and that pointer overwrites the pointer you previously allocate, leading you to lose the pointers to the allocated memory.

There are two solutions: Don't allocate memory (and don't free), or copy into the allocated memory.

Comment: So you could `strdup` (with care and test against failure) the result of `strtok`